# Save data from api call to my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, activerecord

I am looking to save the results of an api call to my model, and am wondering how to approach this..

I have a model called Post and my api call returns what i need it to at the moment. I am just not sure how to get the values returned from the api call into the model, so far i have this

```
def get_feed
  uri = URI(FACEBOOK_URL)
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)
  results = JSON.parse(response.body)
  puts formatted_data(results)
end

def formatted_data(results)
# Return only if there are results
  return unless results
      results['data'].map { |m| 
        {
          message: m['message'],
          picture: m['picture'],
          link: m['link'],
          object_id: m['object_id']
         } }.compact #removes nil objects from array

 Post.where(message: message, picture: picture, link: link, object_id: object_id).first_or_create!
end
```

So if I have 10 instances of message for example, how do i get them all saved into the model

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just iterate over the results['data'] array/hash creating the posts?

Comment: how would i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 def formatted_data(results)
    # Return only if there are results
    return unless results
    results['data'].map { |m|
      attrs = { message: m['message'], picture: m['picture'], link: m['link'], object_id: m['object_id']}
      Post.where(attrs).first_or_create! do |post|
        post.attributes = attrs
      end
    }

  end
```

Assuming that your hash looks like:

```
{
"data" => 
{"key1" => {"message" => "value1", "picture" => "value2", "link" => "value3", "object_id" => "value4" } ,
"key2" => {"message" => "value1", "picture" => "value2", "link" => "value3", "object_id" => "value4" } ,
... 
...
}}
```

Comment: thanks @KirtiThorat that works, i can now see how that second loop works to put attributes into the model :-)

Comment: I don't get why you've done `post.attributes = attrs` those will already be set by the where clause and first_or_create

Answer (score 0):

If you print `results`, it will be clear how you can do that. Than, you can start from here:

```
 messages = results['data'].map{ |m| m['message'] }
```

This will give you all messages in `messages` array

Comment: ok so i get hash rockets, :message => 'text' for example... unsure how to access that, sorry still relatively new to all of this

Comment: Not sure what is you exact question.

If  `rockets=  {:message => 'text' }`, you will get message by: `message = rockets[:message]`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is that the same if there are multiple messages ?

Comment: In that case you have to loop through all the messages, you can read about iterators in ruby [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_iterators.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
def formatted_data(results)
# Return only if there are results
  return unless results
  results['data'].each do |m| 
    Post.where(message: m['message'], picture: m['picture'], link: m['link'], object_id: m['object_id']).first_or_create!
  end 
end
```

Not sure what you mean by - removes nil objects from array.  I assume you mean that facebook returns some data you don't use in which case then check to make sure all the data you want is there before creating a post instance

Comment: well yeah facebook returns a lot of nil entries, but then it all depends on what the user posts i guess